# jQuery code not running

Tags: cewp

I have a piece of jQuery code (an accordion widget that rolls text out and back in to one of several headers when clicked) from someone else in a CEWP that doesn't want to run.  I have multiple suspected issues.

First, I don't know how to tell if jQuery's document.ready() function is firing, or even how to tell if everything is loaded in a way that enables my script to run.

Secondly, the script I'm trying to use requires a version of jQuery that differs from one that my company puts in the master page of the site, of which I don't want to fiddle with.  Is there a way to make sure my script runs only on the version I am trying to target, even though there are 2 versions loaded?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

On the page with your CEWP. Open F12 tool -> Console. Run below script:

```
if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {  
    // jQuery is loaded => print the version
    alert(jQuery.fn.jquery);
}
```

You will get "undefined" if no Jquery is running. Otherwise, you will get the version number alert.

(ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973941/how-to-check-what-version-of-jquery-is-loaded/6973954)

Comment: Thank you for this!

Comment: Please mark it as answer if feasible